# ER vs database schema diagrams

Tags: database

when i search the web for er diagram and database schema these 3 diagram types found but all are named under er diagram.i want to know

- **what is database schema diagram and  what is er diagram**
- **why all are named under er diagram**

[image: diagram 1]
[image: diagram 2]
[image: diagram 3]

Comment: You must ask this question at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Heres a link to the question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119380/er-vs-database-schema-diagrams